# How is this surface integral changed into a volume integral?

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals

A solution $V(\mathbf{x},t) \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}_+)$ to a certain linear hyperbolic partial differential equation can be expressed as:

$$V({\mathbf x}, t)= \frac{1}{4 \pi}\int_0^t\frac{1}{\tau}\int_{S^2(c \tau)}U(\mathbf{x-\xi},t-\tau)d\sigma_{c \tau}(\mathbf{\xi})d\tau$$

for some sufficiently smooth function $U$ on $\mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}_+$. Here 
$$S^2(\tau):=\{\xi \in \mathbb{R}^3:||\xi||=\tau\}$$
is the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\sigma_{\tau}$ is the surface measure on $S^2(\tau)$. What I am having trouble with is the justification for converting the above iterated integral into a single volume integral though a change of variable, $r := c \tau$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
V({\mathbf x}, t)= & \frac{1}{4 \pi}\int_0^{ct}\int_{S^2(r)}\frac{U(\mathbf{x-\xi},t-r/c)}{r}d\sigma_{r}(\mathbf{\xi})dr\\
=&
\frac{1}{4 \pi}\int_{B^3(c \tau)}\frac{U(\mathbf{x-\xi},t-||\xi||/c)}{||\xi||}d\xi
\end{aligned}
$$

Where $B^3(\tau)$ is the ball at the of radius $\tau$ in Euclidean space at the origin. 
I know its a simple manipulation, but I am a bit confused. Is the divergence theorem being employed here?

Comment: No divergence theorem. Just integrating in spherical coordinates in $\Bbb R^3$. No usual "fudge factor" because the radius of the sphere is varying.

Comment: What's a "fudge factor"? please explain a little/

Comment: Oh, I meant that in the usual spherical coordinates set up we integrate $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\int_0^R f(...) \, r^2\sin\phi\, d\rho\,d\phi\,d\theta.$$ Many of us call $r^2\sin\phi$ the "fudge factor" — it's actually a Jacobian determinant. But here you have $\int_{S^2(r)} d\sigma_r$, and $d\sigma_r = r^2\sin\phi\, d\phi\,d\theta$.